# logic - how to convert this formula

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have this formula: 
$$(X \wedge (Y \rightarrow Z)) \vee \neg(\neg X \rightarrow (Y \rightarrow  Z))$$
Is it possible to convert it to this:
$$X ↔ (Y → Z)$$
the truth table show that they are equivalent. Any clues or hints are appreciated also.

Comment: You got stuck on the truth-table?  ... or did the truth-table show that they are not equivalent?  If the latter, you got your answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are equivalent.

Remember that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $(P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)$  ($P \leftrightarrow Q$ means that they're either both true or both false)

So, see if you can convert the first statement to $(X \land (Y \rightarrow Z)) \lor (\neg X \land \neg (Y \rightarrow Z))$

HINT

Use:

**Implication**

$P \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$

and use DeMorgan

Answer (score 1):

We have that
\begin{align}(X \land (Y \rightarrow Z)) \vee \neg(\neg X \rightarrow (Y \rightarrow  Z))&=(X\land(\lnot Y\lor Z))\lor\lnot(X\lor(Y\to Z))\\
&=(X\land(\lnot Y\lor Z))\lor\lnot(X\lor(\lnot Y\lor Z)\\
&=(X\land(\lnot Y\lor Z))\lor(\lnot X\land( Y\land \lnot Z))\\
\end{align}

The other is \begin{align}X\leftrightarrow (Y\to Z)&=\lnot((X\lor(\lnot Y\lor Z))\land\lnot(X\land(\lnot Y\lor Z)))\\
&=(\lnot X\land (Y\land \lnot Z)\lor(X\land(\lnot Y\lor Z))\end{align}
so indeed the two are equivalent.